# Subrelluric forces in a volcanic eruption

Tags: geology, volcanology, terminology, volcanic-eruption

I am listening to a song about volcanoes. It is called "Pyroclastic Annihilation" performed by a brutal deth/thrash metal band called "Demolition Hammer". It is from their album "Epidemic of Violence" released in 1992. The song is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_7qqsVioxo
the full lyrics can be found here:
https://genius.com/Demolition-hammer-pyroclastic-annihilation-lyrics

I have come across a term I do not understand.

> Molten debris
>   Volcanic ash
>   Seas of boiling mud
>   Subrelluric forces exploding violently
>   Pyroclastic matter intense velocity

Is the word "Subrelluric" a geological term? If yes what does it mean exactly? What are Subrelluric forces? What do they do amidst a volcanic eruption? I couldn't find anything on the web. Perhaps this is an extremely advance term not usually used in the public world?

Comment: Maybe edit your question to include the name of the group and where they are from

Comment: Quick googling shows other people asking this question a decade ago in other forums without getting answered :D

Comment: @haresfur question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you heard is “subtelluric” where [telluric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telluric) means “of the earth”.

Comment: This might be it! But if we use it the statement becomes weird: "subtelluric forces exploding violently"? It doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @morbidCode “Sub-earthen forces exploding violently” makes sense to me, am I missing something?

Comment: I guess there isn't under the earth. There surely is under the surface of the earth.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but you can think of it in the same way “terranean” means “of the earth” and “subterranean” means “under the the earth”

Answer (score 3):

This term does not exist in volcanology. I can’t even think of a similar sounding term that can be misheard in the song, or misheard by the authors and then put in the song.

It’s possible it exists in a different language but I am not familiar with any options.

Sounds like your best bet would be to ask the band.

Comment: A quick Google Translate from Latin shows nothing for "rellus" and some other variatios.

Comment: @Gimelist thanks! I am thinking this could be a made-up word for some unknown reason. I might be grasping at straws here, but I edited my question to link the full lyrics. Maybe the meaning of this word is found in the context of the whole lyrics? Thanks again!